# Does $y = x/(1/x)$ contain $x = 0$ in its domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Is $y = x/(1/x)$ equivalent to $y = x^2$, or is there a hole at $x=0$?

Comment: It depends on how you define equality.  Without any other information, I would consider them to be different.

Comment: In my opinion, $~(x=0)~$ is not in the domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say that $x/(1/x)$ and $x^2$ are equivalent, you have already assumed that $x\neq 0$. The two expressions are not equivalent at $x=0.$ The first does not have $x=0$ in its domain.